# How to prepare ethanol-preserved insects for imaging using SEM

Tags: entomology, lab-techniques, microscopy, imaging

I have aquatic insect larvae (soft-bodied) currently preserved in 70% ethanol. I would like to image these using a scanning electron microscope (SEM). I am wondering whether I need to/can start at step 0/1 of the prepping process for the SEM or not:

Do I need to take my specimens out of ethanol, fix them using glutaraldehyde & buffer, wash them in the buffer and then return them to ethanol and dehydrate them with increasing ethanol concentrations?

Or is fixing not necessary for my specimens which are already in ethanol, and could I just increase the ethanol concentration stepwise going up directly from the current 70%?

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: This doesn’t answer your question, but I have some difficulty imagining that someone would give you access to their SEM without going over the various procedures with you. Have times changed so much since I used one in the 70s? Maybe SEMs are dirt cheap now?

Comment: I know what would normally be the required protocol, but I am not sure what to do because my specimens are different. Also the SEM I have access to is not usually used for biological specimens, so there isn't someone I could ask about the specific procedure in my case. If you have an idea I would appreciate the help!

Comment: If there’s no one to ask, I suggest you don’t try anything new. If your SEM isn’t set up for biological specimens, you probably don’t have the equipment necessary to prepare a specimen for a vacuum chamber. The specimen must be devoid of anything that might expand in a vacuum, and a special pressure chamber with the proper materials is needed to do that.

Comment: E.g. [here](https://www.gu.se/en/core-facilities/sem-sample-preparation-techniques). We had a small chamber and used liquid CO2 iirc as the final solution, which was then evaporated off in a vacuum chamber, then coated the specimen in gold. If you started with ethanol, I don’t think the final result will be of highest quality.

Comment: I will say that the final solution doesn’t need to be CO2. There are alternatives you can search for in google scholar. I found a paper that used 100% ethanol and let it air dry. But none that started with ethanol. Wish I had an answer, sorry. Also sorry for the tone of the first comment; it was uncalled for. You clearly know your way around a SEM.